# Cordova - Opening Google maps from app using geo URI - Permission Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app built using Ionic framework & Cordova which uses geo URI to open google maps.

But google maps is not opened. In logs I get following error,

```
/ActivityManager( 2348): Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348): Writing exception to parcel
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2348):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have tried adding following permissions but no luck

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Example URI

```
'geo:0,0?q=' + 'some address like 2/100 ABC street'
```

Cordova version - 4.1.2
Android Target SDK - 19

**Note: It works fine with Cordova 3.5**

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is your app [signed](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)?

Comment: Yes it is signed. Ionic has a release procedure here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Comment: can you post an url example?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Added the URI example

Comment: sorry, I meant the code were you load or redirect to the url

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really faced that, but the fix seems really simple as you only need to add this permission on your *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

Comment: Then you should mention it on your question and I am quite sure that it directly says it on the error message that you are missing that permission.

Answer (score 1):

cordova 3.6.0+ introduced a external application whitelist. You must add  `<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />` to your config.xml .

source: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Opening external app URIs requires some native code to my knowledge, you can't just do it with an `<a href>` link. We solved the problem in Supersonic by implementing a separate API for that: http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/app/openurl/

If you want to check this out, you can use our [Steroids tooling](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids/) to [run your Cordova app](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) with our wrapper, though you'll need to include the `steroids.js` and `supersonic.js` libraries by hand to access the APIs.

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer at AppGyver).

Comment: in most cases you can use inAppBrowser plugin with _system option, or whitelisting the url in the config.xml works with some url schemes too

Comment: @harsa_ using geo URI you can call the Google Maps app. The geo URI will redirect to google maps app if its installed on phone otherwise it will open maps in browser. It worked when I had Cordova version 3.5. I do not think I need to write my own API to achieve this. See the URI scheme here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme